# Using loc in pandas without discarding the outer levels

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing

I have a dataframe like

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'level0': [0,1,2],
    'level1': ['a', 'b', 'b'],
    'level2':['x', 'x', 'x'],
    'data': [0.12, 0.34, 0.45]}
).set_index(['level0', 'level1', 'level2'])
```

| level0 | level1 | level 2 | data |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | a | x | 0.12 |
| 1 | b | x | 0.34 |
| 2 | b | x | 0.56 |

If `level0`, `level1`, and `level2` are the index levels, I want to access the data at `(2, b)` but keep the first two levels of labels. If I do `df.loc[(2, 'b')]` the output is

| level2 | data |
| --- | --- |
| x | 0.56 |

but my desired output is

| level0 | level1 | level 2 | data |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | b | x | 0.56 |

How do I keep the levels 0 and 1 while using `loc`? I could add these levels back afterwards, but this is slightly annoying, and I'm doing this frequently enough to wonder if there's a one step solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the output of [`MultiIndex.get_locs`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.get_locs.html) in `iloc`:

```
>>> df.iloc[df.index.get_locs((2, 'b'))]

                      data
level0 level1 level2      
2      b      x       0.45
```

Answer (score 1):

Another potentially cleaner solution may be to use a `slice` with the same beginning and end points:

```
>>> df.loc[slice((2, 'b'), (2, 'b'))]

                      data
level0 level1 level2      
2      b      x       0.45
```

This is especially helpful if the name of your dataframe is long.

I've come across situations where you can leave off the second tuple, but it doesn't work all the time, so it's probably safer to include it.

Comment: I posted [a new answer](/a/77348658/4518341) that you might like :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a list to keep the index. With a MultiIndex, that means a tuple of lists, one for each level.

```
df.loc[([2], ['b']),]
```

```
                      data
level0 level1 level2      
2      b      x       0.45
```

The trailing comma is required to avoid ambiguity, since `x[(a, b)]` is equivalent to `x[a, b]`.

For more info, see the User Guide: [Advanced indexing with hierarchical index](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/advanced.html#advanced-indexing-with-hierarchical-index)